# Can I tail the log on a Cisco Router?

Tags: networking, cisco, router

Can I tail the log on a Cisco Router?  I have 'logging buffered 51200' and a debug running.  I can see the packets with 'show log'.  Can I tail this?

Comment: If you need to jump quickly to the last lines of the log, `term length 0` before `sh log`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sure, run `logging monitor debug` (or any other level) then `terminal monitor`.
Log will be displayed on your (and only your) Telnet/SSH session.
If you are connected using the console port, use `logging console`.

This will enable a behaviour similar to `tail -f`.

Comment: To clarify a bit, "logging monitor <level>" set globally the level, then "terminal monitor" enable session per session to display log on the terminal (using the globally defined level).

Comment: This is a tail -f rather than a tail, I'm not sure what the original poster had in mind.

Answer (score 2):

Sending to syslog is the better way to do, but here's a trick you might find useful:

You can do "show logging | begin *regexp*" and it will show you the log starting at any lines matching that regexp.

That way, if you have your logs being time-stamped (you do, right?) You can something like:

show logging | begin ^Sep  3*

(note there is a double space after "Sep" but this text editor eats it) and it will show you all logs starting from September 3rd, for example.

Requires some experimentation to get it right. :)

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this is to set a syslog host and by sending data log to it you can watch events in realtime. 
You could also try adjusting the console messages with logging console debug